# Does Cloudfront keep serving the cached response after receiving an error from the origin on updating the call?

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront

We have setup Cloudfront with our own server as its origin and have a json call that is cached for 60 seconds (max-age), and say we successfully cache the response in Cloudfront. Now what happens when Cloudfront tries to update the json response after 60 seconds by calling our server and our server responds with an error (or no response at all when it is down). Does it keep on serving the old response, or return an error?

Answer (score 1):

According to the api docs:

If your origin server is unavailable and CloudFront gets a request for an object that is in the edge cache
but that has expired (for example, because the period of time specified in the Cache-Control max-age
directive has passed), CloudFront continues to serve the expired version of the object. For more information
about object expiration